# apache htaccess how do i remove a string from url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The below link was markes as a solution but it is not this is not a domain issue this is a url issue as in the part that comes after the domain name.
[Apache RewriteRule to remove port on any domain name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611521/apache-rewriterule-to-remove-port-on-any-domain-name)

example structure

```
/grid is a folder
/hypergrid.php/ is a file
/:80 is god knows what and needs to be gone
/foreignagent is variable
/ff11bc47-2deb-a55a-9531-08706d736121 is the variable value
```

I have a program that sends data to a website. bellow is a example of a request from this program.

i do not know why it is injecting a port in the middle of the url but i do not want to rewrite the software. how do i remove :80 from the url using htaccess?

```
/grid/hypergrid.php/:80/foreignagent/ff11bc47-2deb-a55a-9531-08706d736121/
```

this url should look like

```
/grid/hypergrid.php/foreignagent//
```

this part of the url is not static `

```
foreignagent/ff11bc47-2deb-a55a-9531-08706d736121/`
```

Comment: Have you seen [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611521/apache-rewriterule-to-remove-port-on-any-domain-name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611521/apache-rewriterule-to-remove-port-on-any-domain-name)

Comment: the proble is that the port is in the middle of the url i dont need to replace a domain port i need to remove :80 from anywhere it may be put in the url

Comment: Yep. But can you not match the port in the regex and $1 the captured group before and after?

Comment: I do not know wht you mean

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^:80/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

This assumes the client will follow redirects. If not you'll likely need something like `ProxyPass`, which won't work in `.htaccess` but needs to be in the Apache config files.

Comment: [Sat Oct 17 12:39:26.131358 2015] [core:error] [pid 3288:tid 2232] (20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: [client 64.31.16.122:48072] AH00127: Cannot map POST /grid/hypergrid.php/:80/foreignagent/ff11bc47-2deb-a55a-9531-e8706d736121/ HTTP/1.1 to file

Comment: Ahh, a little different perspective after the edits. Perhaps: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/:80/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [R=301,L]`

Comment: will hogan your answer is the closest except for making it a redirect i can not redirect. can this rule stip from the url?

Comment: You can remove the 301, `RewriteRule ^(.*)/:80/(.*)$ /$1/$2 [L]`. This doesn't strip it, but returns the response from the functioning URL. To actually change the request URL (stripping the :80) sent to Apache, you need to either proxy or use a redirect.