# redirect and hide port (folder) in apache virtualhost - xwiki

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mod-rewrite, apache2, virtualhost

Env: Ubuntu 18, Apache2, XWiki 12.1 on JETTY 9.4

I have xwiki on `https://wiki.company.com:8443/xwiki/` and I would like to hide port `8443` and optionaly `/xwiki/`.
I have tried with virtualhost:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/company.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/comapny.key

    ProxyPass / https://wiki.company.com:8443/xwiki/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://wiki.company.com:8443/xwiki/
</VirtualHost>
```

This similar solution works for many projects but not for xwiki. The problem is that in this solution xwiki has problem with loading some files because it still try to load files from
`https://wiki.company.com/xwiki/webjars/wiki%3Axwiki/drawer/2.4.0/css/drawer.min.css`

instead of

`https://wiki.hl-display.com/webjars/wiki%3Axwiki/drawer/2.4.0/css/drawer.min.css`

So maybe is there any other solution like removing `xwiki`

```
    ProxyPass / https://wiki.company.com:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://wiki.company.com:8443/
```

and redirect user when enter in browser exact `https://wiki.company.com` to `https://wiki.company.com/xwiki/`

Or mod rewrite to replace string

`https://wiki.company.com/xwiki/hhh/jjj/aaa`

To

`https://wiki.company.com/hhh/jjj/aaa`
?

I have try a lot of settings but without any success :(

Comment: You can try redirecting it through htaccess.

Comment: Xwiki is installed on JETTY 9,4. I use Apache Virtualost.

Comment: Rewrite conditions can be written in apache virtual host configuration file.

Comment: Can you help me with Rewrite condition? I have try a lot of combinations without any success :(

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9611521/apache-rewriterule-to-remove-port-on-any-domain-name

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found solution :) By adding 3 lines in VirtualHost

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wiki.company.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xwiki/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xwiki/ [R=301,L]
```

So now when user enter exact URL: `https://wiki.company.com` it will redirect to `https://wiki.company.com\xwiki\`. So wiki works, port is hidden and nice URL works :)

so complete code is:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN Off
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/company.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/private/company.key

    RewriteEngine on
    ServerName https://wiki.company.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} wiki.company.com$ [NC]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xwiki/(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /xwiki/ [R=301,L]
    ProxyPass / https://wiki.company.com:8443/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://wiki.company.com:8443/
</VirtualHost>
```